# Can an array of strings of size 1 be used like a string?

Tags: vbscript

I'm translating a program from asp to asp.net. The creator has a few function that I'm scratching my head over. It seems to be passing back arrays but the results of the function are used as if they're strings in some situations and arrays in others.

Mostly it operates as if it returns a string but sometimes it'll do for each on the result which indicates that it's actually an array of strings. I've searched the web to see if there's some weird corner case logic but nothing specific to this comes up.

```vb
function textvalue(myPar)
{
    eval("var anotherArray=" + myPar);
    anotherArray.sort();

    if (eval("datatype" + myPar)=="datetime")
    {
        //if (eval(myPar)==null || eval(myPar)=="null" || eval(myPar)=="")
        if (anotherArray.toString()==null || anotherArray.toString()=="null" || anotherArray.toString()=="")
        {
            return anotherArray;
        }
        else
        {
            return new Array(convertFromAODdatetime(anotherArray.toString()));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return anotherArray;
    }
}

USE 1
Response.Write(...existing status: " & theStructure.textvalue("structureItemStatus") & "....")

USE 2
For Each datum In fileData.textValue("fileNomenclature")
                            Response.Write(...
```

I'm ultimately wondering if I need to do something unique w/ these functions or maybe the resulting datatype to replicate the logic of the function properly.

Comment: Original code isn't VBScript, not sure why question is tagged as VBScript. Is this all the code you are working with?

Comment: The main function textValue is definitely vbscript. The uses of it are used in asp code. Is the uses what you're referring to?

Comment: If anything, it's perhaps [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), but not [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript).

Comment: You know... now that I look closely... I see what you're saying. Thanks for the heads up all. The remainder of the code is vbscript but this is an object referenced in asp classic which has to be written in a wsc file and I guess he decided he'd switch languages for this. I guess I don't even notice the language differences like var vs dim any more...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that an array works that way. You might be able to replace the array with a list and it work more in the way you are expecting.

Another option is to just run an if statement to see if the array length is greater than 1 then run a foreach loop otherwise just grab arry[0].